# How to click on the first Yahoo search result using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, search, yahoo

How can I click on the first search result on Yahoo? I've tried every possible XPATH and also both web driver wait method and the standart method. but none of them worked. I'm using Python Selenium.

My code:

```
    import sys
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    def element(driver, by_x, html_element):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((by_x, html_element))
            )
            return element
        except:
            print("Element not found")

    def get_numbers(string):
        numbers_list = [string[i] for i in range(len(string)) if string[i].isnumeric()]
        number = "".join(numbers_list)
        return number

    class movieRatingScraper: 
        def __init__(self, film):
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./drivers/chromedriver", options=options)
            self.film = film
            self.driver.get(f"https://search.yahoo.com/search?p={self.film}")

        def info(self):
            # THE PROBLEM
            element(self.driver, By.XPATH, "//*[@id='yui_3_10_0_1_1609677350466_629']").click()

        def rt_rating(self):
            WebDriverWait(self.driver,     10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"agree"))).click()
            rt_string = element(self.driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "rottenTomatoes")
            rt_rating = get_numbers(rt_string.text)
            print(rt_rating)
            return rt_rating

        def get_current_url(self):
            return self.driver.current_url

        def quit(self):
            self.driver.quit()

    movie = movieRatingScraper("tenet")
    ratings = movie.rt_rating()
    movie.info()
    movie.get_current_url()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is an issue with the xpath that you are using in order click on the first result. Could please check the below xpath and let me know whether it works for you or not.

```
(//div[@id='web']/descendant::li[@class='first'])[1]/descendant::a[1]
```

One more thing, I believe that you need to call the below method before executing the rt_rating(). Please verify the same.

```
movie.info()
```